# Question on nilpotent transformation and basis

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $V$ be a finite dimensional vector space and $F: V \to V$ be a nilpotent linear transform i.e., $F^q = 0$ for some $q \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$. Suppose we have $q_1, q_2, \dots, q_r \in \mathbb{Z^{+}}$ and $v_1, v_2, \dots, v_r \in V$ such that for each $v_i$:
$$
F^{q_i - 1}(v_i) \neq 0, \; F^{q_i}(v_i) = 0, \; v_i \notin \text{Im} F
$$
Suppose that
$$
\{F^{q_1-1}(v_1),F^{q_2-1}(v_2),\dots,F^{q_r-1}(v_r)\}
$$
forms a basis of $\ker F$, is it true that
$$
\left\{
\begin{array}{cccc}
F^{q_1-1}(v_1),\;F^{q_1-2}(v_1),\;\dots,\;v_1 \\
F^{q_2-1}(v_2),\;F^{q_2-2}(v_2),\;\dots,\;v_2 \\
\dots \\
F^{q_r-1}(v_r),\;F^{q_r-2}(v_r),\;\dots,\;v_r
\end{array}
\right.
$$
forms a basis of $V$?
It is not really hard to see that they are linearly independent, but I am having hard time showing that they span $V$.